# Disabling ARC... (AdMob SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, admob

I've added all of the files and the frameworks needed to run the Admob SDK, but the problem is ARC...

My project uses ARC, but the AdMob files don't use ARC. I know you can disable ARC on specific files via the *"Compile Sources"* section which is under your project menu -> Targets (App Name) -> Build Phases

The problem is that the AdMob files don't show up in the Compile Sources section or any other section. You can see my AdMob folder in the Project Navigator...

**Why won't these files show up so I can disable ARC on them?**

[image: Xcode AdMob]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're not compiling Admob .m files, but rather it's a library you've included in your project and you're just using the .h files for the interfaces. So you might not need to worry about ARC v non-ARC issue at all. You can frequently use non-ARC libraries in ARC projects. The main issue is whether the library conforms to the rules outlined in [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), such as the standard naming conventions, where the only methods that return an object with a +1 `retainCount` begin with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, and `mutableCopy`.

You only need the `-fno-objc-arc` option if you're compiling the library's source in your project.

Comment: Moreover, I strongly recommand to include any external code (like the Facebook SDK or SBJSON in your case) in the form of a library/separate xcodeproj in your workspace, that is having a workspace containing one xcodeproj for your own app code and one xcodeproj for each external library (Facebook.xcodeproj, SBJSON.xcodeproj, …). That way each project/external library can have its own build settings (including turning ON or OFF ARC). Much more efficient than adding -fno-objc-arc everywhere _(especially if you happen to update your external libraries or add files to them and forget this flag)_.